# NFS client does not recover if server reboots

Tags: mount, nfs

There are two machines: (a) is the NFS server and (b) is the NFS client.
When machine (a) reboots is there a way to recover the NFS client on machine (b) without a reboot?

Comment: What OS is running on the NFS client? What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Fedora 15 and 22.  Not really seeing any errors, but if I `ls` the mount point the shell just hangs there.

Comment: Is there anything in the system logs on the clients detailing the NFS errors?

Comment: Curious if the server is OK after the reboot. On a client that is hanging, can you successfully manually  mount the server's filesystem on a different mount point?

Comment: I'm seeing this error in `Dec 29 21:49:08 localhost kernel: [133067.342478] nfs: server <server hostname> not responding, still trying` on the client.

Comment: On the client, does `showmount -e server-hostname` show the expected list of exported filesystems?

Comment: Are you using NFSv3 or older? If so, is the `rpc.statd` service running on both client and server? It is necessary to allow the NFS client/server to detect that the server/client has rebooted, and to automatically recover in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by the word `recover` but if you mean to `remount` then yes, it is as simple as `sudo mount -a`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using fstab.  I just run `mount` manually.

Comment: well then maybe you should.

Comment: should it not be mount -a -o remount?

Comment: You can do a remount if you want but if the server was rebooted, it is a good chance that the mount is lost, if it isn't then I would only remount that instead of everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `umount -f mountpoint`

I have seen this a lot on my RHEL 7 machines connected to a Windows NFS server. The umount command will fail, but it will release whatever is keeping the client from operating.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three possible trouble spots:

- `rpc.statd` and its port assignment
- hostnames used internally in the NFS protocol
- non-persistently assigned filesystem IDs (`fsid`s) on the server side

### `rpc.statd`

If the NFS share is hard-mounted, any processes accessing the share will hang during the NFS server reboot, but they should recover automatically as soon as the NFS server is fully up and running again. If that does not happen, something is wrong.

NFS version 4 has all the recovery functions use the same network port (normally 2049/TCP), but older protocol versions had the Network Status Monitor sub-protocol as a separate service, usually known as `rpc.statd`. This process must be running on both NFSv2/v3 client *and* server systems, and both the NFS client and server must be able to connect to the `rpc.statd` of the other party or else the NFS connection may not recover normally after either system reboots. (See [`man sm-notify`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sm-notify.8.html#NSM_OPERATION_IN_DETAIL) if you need further details. Look for a paragraph titled `NSM OPERATION IN DETAIL`; `sm-notify` is the component that actively sends the reboot notification to `rpc.statd`.)

Historically, `rpc.statd` used to be located in a dynamically-assigned port number, and you were supposed to first query the `portmapper`/`rpcbind` service (always in port 111, both UDP and TCP) for the port number currently used by `rpc.statd`.

Such dynamically-assigned ports are undesirable in modern firewalled networks, as the best practice is to allow traffic in the minimum necessary number of ports only. So, if there are any firewalls in between the NFSv2/v3 server and its clients, making `rpc.statd` and other NFSv2/v3 sub-protocols use fixed port numbers would be an important step towards improving NFS reliability.

The exact procedure will depend on the OS and its version: ultimately it usually ends up being an added option and port number for the `rpc.statd` process, but many OSs and Linux distributions include some functionality for this, so you might need to just uncomment a setting in a configuration file or a shell variable in a `rpc.statd` startup script.

In the NFSv3 server, the port numbers of `rpc.mountd` and `lockd`/`nlockmgr` should be likewise locked down to fixed values. In clients, you'll only need to care about `rpc.statd` (and perhaps `lockd` if you use file locking on NFS).

In RHEL 7 and older, you might achieve this by adding these lines to the end of `/etc/sysconfig/network`:

```
LOCKD_TCPPORT=4045
LOCKD_UDPPORT=4045
STATD_PORT=4046
MOUNTD_PORT=4047
# PCNFSD_PORT=4048
RQUOTAD_PORT=4049
```

In RHEL 8 and newer, there are commented-out example lines in `/etc/nfs.conf`. Comment out and edit lines to produce this:

```
[lockd]
port=4045
udp-port=4045

[mountd]
port=4047

[statd]
port=4046
```

In Debian and related distributions, the required settings are in different files:

- `STATDOPTS="-p 4046"` in `/etc/default/nfs-common`
- `RPCMOUNTDOPTS="-p 4047"` in `/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server`
- `options lockd nlm_udpport=4045 nlm_tcpport=4045` in `/etc/modprobe.d/nfs-options.conf` (create it if it does not exist).

After adding these settings and restarting the appropriate NFS services (or rebooting), you can use `rpcinfo -p` to confirm that the NFSv3 sub-protocols will now be getting fixed port numbers.

(The above-mentioned port numbers are also the ones [the NFSv3 service of a NetApp NAS device](https://docs.netapp.com/us-en/ontap/nfs-admin/modify-ports-used-nfsv3-services-task.html) will use by default, with the exception that NetApp will place `rpc.mountd` to port 635.)

### Hostnames

The protocol of `rpc.statd` uses hostnames, not IP addresses: both the client and the server must be able to look up their canonical hostname from the IP address. If this cannot be done, then the `sm-notify` cannot send out a valid reboot notification to the other party of the NFS connection, and recovery after a reboot may fail.

There is an asymmetry in the NFS protocol: the NFS server will automatically get to know its clients' hostnames (known as `caller_name`s in the NFS protocol) and provide them to the server-side `rpc.statd`, but there is no equivalent interaction that would inform the client of the server's hostname. So if the `mount` command was specified using an IP address, and the client cannot reverse-map that IP address into a hostname, then the client will have no clue as to which name the NFS server will call itself when it sends a reboot notification to the client-side `rpc.statd`.

This suggests that using IP addresses in the `mount` command might be a bad idea if you want the NFS mount to automatically recover from a server reboot successfully. You would also have to ensure the name used in the client's `mount` command matches the name the NFS server actually uses for itself.

### Non-persistent `fsid`s

Modern Linux NFS servers will automatically use filesystem UUIDs (if available) as NFS `fsid`s. Those `fsid`s should be persistent by default.

But older Unixes and other NFS implementations may still use the older small-integers style `fsid`s, and some of them might even assign them randomly in a non-persistent fashion unless configured otherwise. If so, then after the NFS server reboots, the client will produce `stale file handle` error messages when trying to access the mounted NFS share until the share is unmounted and remounted. The fix for this is to ensure that the `fsid`s are assigned persistently at the NFS server.

(I once saw this when a trio of HP-UX systems running as a failover cluster (HP ServiceGuard) was acting as a fault-tolerant NFS server. If the `fsid`s were not explicitly defined in the NFS export/share configuration, the clients would fail after the NFS service failed over from one node to another, which defeated the purpose of the failover cluster. After nailing down the `fsid`s, the failovers started working as expected.)